# Buzz when strumming a new Fender Performer HSS Strat

Tags: buzz, stratocaster

So this is a bit annoying for me as 3 days ago I got my first Performer Strat HSS and it was buzzing on the low E as I was playing the Pentatonic on the A Minor. Here is the related post:

[Fender Performer Strat HSS Buzz on the Low E String](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/95162/fender-performer-strat-hss-buzz-on-the-low-e-string/95171#95171)

I took it back to the shop yesterday and they suggested me that they will exchange that for another copy which I did! With this one, I do not see any more buzz when picking the A Minor pentatonic, but I notice the buzz when strumming the power chords. How could this be that the copy that I got also has this buzzing issue. I'm now starting to think if this is my technique that is the culprit? If this was my technique issue then why is that with the copy that I had before I was able to hear the buzz when picking the A Minor Pentatonic and with this new copy there is zero buzz when playing the A Minor Pentatonic.

I quickly checked the neck and it is pretty straight without any forward or backward bow. Should I add some relief? Should I lower the action? The problem I'm facing is it buzzes a lot when I strum the G5, A5, B5, C5 and D5 Power chords. This is annoying to me. I have been saving money for almost a year to get this beloved instrument. How many forums, how many questions and after lots of research comparing between Gibson, PRS, Ibanez, I decided to get this particular Strat. But now having to see this buzz is just letting me down. How can I resolve this my Strat friends!

Comment: Back to the shop - explain and show!

Comment: Are you sure? Would that mean that I should return this and forget getting another Strat? The shop will try to set it up again and it might or it might not work out after they set it up.

Comment: Don't say things until I'm sure - usually! When it's set up, you play it in the shop. A set up is an individual, personal thing. I could set up a guitar, and some players would say it's great, others o.k. and some say don't like it. They're all right!

Comment: Give me some time I have recored a video of the problem that I face. I will upload that to Youtube and you tell me if the problem I face is real or it is my technique that needs improvement!

Comment: Ok here is the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRYRayYk3es&feature=youtu.be

Comment: And here is another one - https://youtu.be/C_8VVDa76Cw

Comment: Can't hear any buzzing on the vids. Sounds just like a Strat should! Changes need to be smarter, but that's not the issue. Seems o.k. to me.

Comment: That sounds relieving to me. May be it is just my technique that needs some refinement. This copy that I have now is actually a lot better as the old one was buzzing even when I was picking it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I listened to the two recordings you posted and I'm not really hearing any issues with the guitar. There is slight buzzing in the recordings but I think it's instead related to your chord-changing technique.

Try the following:

- Make sure you're pressing hard enough on the strings
- Make sure you're not strumming too hard (and thus messing up your grip on the strings)
- Try to hold the chord for as long as you can before playing the next one

The last point is the most important. I think the buzzing is the worst on the last chords you play because you're thinking ahead about moving all the way back to the starting chord, causing you to relax/lift off too early.

Comment: I will try following your advice!

Answer (score 1):

> it buzzes a lot when I strum the G5, A5, B5, C5 and D5 Power chords.

If the neck is straight, the strings at the bridge could be a little low.  Maybe just raise them up the smallest amount, measure, retune and play.